# Bouncing Ball (in class) - need help coding array

Tags: java, arrays, processing

I'm all new to this and doing a beginner's lecture on Java (with Processing). Our assignment this time is the bouncing ball. I've (sort of) successfully gotten it to move the way it's supposed to and put it into a class, but I can't get the array right.

Here's the version using the class:

```
class Ball {
float x;
  float y;
  float ySpeed;
  float gravity;

int counter = 0;

Ball()
{ 
x = 300;
y = 300;

ySpeed = 2.5;
gravity = 0.2;

}

void move()
{
  y = y + ySpeed;
   ySpeed = ySpeed + gravity;

  if (y > height-25 )

  {ySpeed = ySpeed * -0.85;
 y = height-25;

 counter++;
  }
  println(counter);

 if(counter >= 17)
 {ySpeed=0;
 y=height-25;}
}


void display()
{
  ellipse(x,y,50,50);
}
}

//using the class:
Ball b1;

void settings()
{
  size(800,600);
}

void setup()
{
  b1 = new Ball();
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  b1.move();
  b1.display();
  }
```

Here's what I ended up with after messing it up completely.

```
    //class Ball 
class Ball {
float[] x;
  float[] y;
  float[] ySpeed;
  float[] gravity;
  int i;

int counter = 0;

//constructor
Ball()
{ 
x[i] = 300;
y[i] = 300;

ySpeed[i] = 2.5;
gravity[i] = 0.2;


}

void move()
{
  y[i] = y[i] + ySpeed[i];
   ySpeed[i] = ySpeed[i] + gravity[i];

  //changes direction; (-25) to avoid movement beyong boundary

  if (y[i] > height-25 )

  {ySpeed[i] = ySpeed[i] * -0.85;
 y[i] = height-25;

  }
  println(counter);


 if(counter >= 17)
 {ySpeed[i]=0;
 y[i]=height-25;}
}


void display()
{
//draw ellipse
  ellipse(x[i],y[i],50,50);
}
}

 //using the class
 final int i = 9;
Ball[] Balle =  new Ball[10];

void settings()
{
  size(800,600);
}

void setup()
{

  Balle[i] = new Ball();
  for (int i = 0; i < Balle.length; i++)
  {Balle[i] = new Ball(x[i],y[i],50,50), i*4);
  }
      }
```

I suppose this looks weird because it's picked together from several different help pages... the current error is "variable x does not exist" on

```
{Balle[i] = new Ball(x[i],y[i],50,50), i*4);
```

I'm aware there are several other problems.

Right now I'm quite lost in figuring out how it works. Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't compile for 12+ reasons. Please edit your question.

Comment: Even if the code is a combination from several sources it still can have proper indentation. It will also help you to read the code yourself and save you some errors.

Comment: You've got code outside of a class and many other errors. If I were you, I'd scrap this code and start over, and then compile the code early and often (or use an IDE). Never add new lines of code to code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Do you usually post the last version that was working? I'll put that one into the question... the one I posted is what I'm stuck with now.

Answer (score 0):

***variable x does not exist*** - It's because you don't have x as a global variable, but as a class variable, which is therefore only accessible from within the Ball class or by an instance of the Ball class. I don't exactly know why you're using arrays for x and y, primitives would do just fine. And don't forget to add the draw() method, as in processing, that serves as the 'main loop', it gets executed every 0.x sec (frameRate) so you MUST use that as well. Your other functions like display() etc.. can also be called from within the draw function.

Comment: Isn't this an instance of the class? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Geez, what did I even do there?

Here it is:

```
Ball[] balls = new Ball[10];

void settings()
{
  size(600,800);
}


void setup()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
{
  balls[i] = new Ball();
}
}

void draw()
{ background(0);
 for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
 {
balls[i].move();
balls[i].display();
}
}
```

Is programming like that, stumbling around in the dark until you get hit by a brick...?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pseudo code.

If ball <= bottom, reverse the speed of ball. 
(That means when it hits the floor, the speed reverses. Multiply it with -1)

Other wise, speedOfBall = speed - (gravity*time);

You can easily calculate the displacement in terms of coordinates as s = velocity*time + .5*gravity*time^2.